# Python Replace \\ with \

Tags: python, string, replace, double, slash

So I can't seem to figure this out... I have a string say, `"a\\nb"` and I want this to become `"a\nb"`. I've tried all the following and none seem to work;

```
>>> a
'a\\nb'
>>> a.replace("\\","\")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.replace("\\","\")
                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> a.replace("\\",r"\")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.replace("\\",r"\")
                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> a.replace("\\",r"\\")
'a\\\\nb'
>>> a.replace("\\","\\")
'a\\nb'
```

I really don't understand why the last one works, because this works fine:

```
>>> a.replace("\\","%")
'a%nb'
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

**EDIT** I understand that \ is an escape character. What I'm trying to do here is turn all `\\n` `\\t` etc. into `\n` `\t` etc. and replace doesn't seem to be working the way I imagined it would.

```
>>> a = "a\\nb"
>>> b = "a\nb"
>>> print a
a\nb
>>> print b
a
b
>>> a.replace("\\","\\")
'a\\nb'
>>> a.replace("\\\\","\\")
'a\\nb'
```

I want string a to look like string b. But replace isn't replacing slashes like I thought it would.

Comment: Your original string, `a = 'a\\nb'` does not actually have two `'\'` characters, the first one is an escape for the latter. If you do, `print a`, you'll see that you actually have only one `'\'` character.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's no need to use replace for this.

What you have is a encoded string (using the `string_escape` encoding) and you want to decode it:

```
>>> s = r"Escaped\nNewline"
>>> print s
Escaped\nNewline
>>> s.decode('string_escape')
'Escaped\nNewline'
>>> print s.decode('string_escape')
Escaped
Newline
>>> "a\\nb".decode('string_escape')
'a\nb'
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode('\\n\\x21', 'unicode_escape')
'\n!'
```

Comment: I think the equivalent of this for Python 3 is: `bytes(s, 'utf-8').decode("unicode_escape")`

Comment: Alternatively in Python 3: `'a\\nb'.encode().decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: @JonathanHartley  you should submit this as a separate answer.

Comment: No, you should!

Comment: This won't remove the double slash in all cases, for instance \\N will fail. print(codecs.decode('\\N\\x21', 'unicode_escape')) w/error message "malformed \N character escape. "

Comment: as mentioned by @born_naked, this does not remove the double slash in all cases. It is not a general solution specially for recent python versions.

Answer (score 13):

You are missing, that \ is the escape character.

Look here: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html
at 2.4.1 "Escape Sequence"

Most importantly \n is a newline character.
And \\ is an escaped escape character :D

```
>>> a = 'a\\\\nb'
>>> a
'a\\\\nb'
>>> print a
a\\nb
>>> a.replace('\\\\', '\\')
'a\\nb'
>>> print a.replace('\\\\', '\\')
a\nb
```

Answer (score 3):

```
r'a\\nb'.replace('\\\\', '\\')
```

or

```
'a\nb'.replace('\n', '\\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original string, `a = 'a\\nb'` does not actually have two `'\'` characters, the first one is an escape for the latter. If you do, `print a`, you'll see that you actually have only one `'\'` character.

```
>>> a = 'a\\nb'
>>> print a
a\nb
```

If, however, what you mean is to interpret the `'\n'` as a newline character, without escaping the slash, then:

```
>>> b = a.replace('\\n', '\n')
>>> b
'a\nb'
>>> print b
a
b
```

Comment: This worked thanks! Part of the issue was that I was confusing myself by thinking that \\n was 3 characters instead of just 2.

Comment: it's worse: '\n' is just one character: 0x0d

Answer (score 1):

It's because, even in "raw" strings (=strings with an `r` before the starting quote(s)), an unescaped escape character cannot be the last character in the string. This should work instead:

```
'\\ '[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python string literals, backslash is an escape character. This is also true when the interactive prompt shows you the value of a string. It will give you the literal code representation of the string. Use the `print` statement to see what the string actually looks like.

This example shows the difference:

```
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> print '\\'
\
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 it will be:

```
bytes(s, 'utf-8').decode("unicode_escape")
```

Answer (score -1):

This works on Windows with Python 3.x:

```
import os
str(filepath).replace(os.path.sep, '/')
```

Where: `os.path.sep` is `\` on Windows and `/` on Linux.

### Case study

Used this to prevent errors when generating a Markdown file then rendering it to `pdf`.

Answer (score -2):

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Programming\\Downloads"
# Replace \\ with a \ along with any random key multiple times
path.replace('\\', '\pppyyyttthhhooonnn')
# Now replace pppyyyttthhhooonnn with a blank string
path.replace("pppyyyttthhhooonnn", "")

print(path)
```

#Output...
C:\Users\Programming\Downloads