# Python os.listdir and path with escape character

Tags: python

I have a string variable that I have read from a file which is a path that contains an escape character i.e.

```
dir="...Google\\ Drive"
```

I would like to then list all the files and directories in that path with os.listdir i.e.

```
os.listdir(dir)
```

But I get this error (because I really only want one escape):

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '....Google\\ Drive/'
```

I have tried using

```
os.listdir(r'....Google\ Drive')

os.listdir(dir.replace("\\","\"))

os.listdir(dir.decode('string_escape'))
```

all to no avail. I read this [Python Replace \\ with \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186839/python-replace-with), but "...Google\ drive".decode('string_escape') != "...Google\ Drive".

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried omitting escapes?

Comment: Have you tried using os.path.join() to join the path and get the proper directory?

Comment: I am reading this path string from a file (could be an arbitrary path), but @Amber I guess I could do os.listdir(dir.replace("\\","")). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the path could be arbitrary , you can split the the strings using `\\` removing any '' you may get along the way and then do `os.path.join` , Example -

```
>>> import os.path
>>> l = "Google\Drive\\\\ Temp"
>>> os.path.join(*[s for s in l.split('\\') if l != ''])
'Google\\Drive\\ Temp'
```

Then you can use that in os.listdir() to list the directories.