# How i can replace in a list of strings "\\" with "\" in Python

Tags: python, string, list, replace, special-characters

In my code i have a list of locations and the output of a list is like this

`['D:\\Todo\\VLC\\Daft_Punk\\One_more_time.mp4"', ...`

i want a replace "\\" with "\"
(listcancion is a list with all strings)
 i try to remplace with this code `remplacement = [listcancion.replace('\\', '\') for listcancion in listcancion]` or this `remplacement = [listcancion.replace('\\\\', '\\') for listcancion in listcancion]` or also this `remplacement = [listcancion.replace('\\', 'X') for listcancion in listcancion]
listrandom = [remplacement.replace('X', '\') for remplacement in remplacement]`

I need to change only the character \ i can't do it things like this `("\\Todo", "\Todo")` because i have more characters to remplace.

If i can solved without imports thats great.

Comment: Those already are single backslash characters. You don't need to do any replacement. You're just not yet familiar with how `repr` and escaping work, so you're getting confused by how the list is displayed.

Comment: The backslash is an escape character in Python.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186839/python-replace-with

Comment: @krishnakant No, that deals with a slightly different issue, AFAICT. Or at least, on a different level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of string representations.

First, you have to differentiate between a string's "real" content and its representation.

A string's "real" content might be letters, digits, punctuation and so on, which makes displaying it quite easy. But imagine a strring which contains `a`, a line break and a `b`. If you print that string, you get the output

```
a
b
```

which is what you expect.

But in order to make it more compact, this string's representation is `a\nb`: the line break is represented as `\n`, the `\` serving as an escape character. Compare the output of `print(a)` (which is the same as `print(str(a))`) and of `print(repr(a))`.

Now, in order not to confuse this with a string which contains `a`, `\`, `n` and `b`, a "real" backslash in a string has a representation of `\\` and the same string, which prints as `a\nb`, has a representation of `a\\nb` in order to distinguish that from the first example.

If you print a list of anything, it is displayed as a comma-separated list of the representations of their components, even if they are strings.

If you do

```
for element in listcancion:
    print(element)
```

you'll see that the string actually contains only one `\` where its representation shows `\\`.

(Oh, and BTW, I am not sure that things like `[listcancion.<something> for listcancion in listcancion]` work as intended; better use another variable as the loop variablen, such as `[element.<something> for element in listcancion]`.)