# Replace "\\" with "\" in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, string, windows, path

I have a string containing a filepath for Windows:

```
import os
dir = os.getcwd()
# bogus name
'C:\\my\\folder'
```

If I copy and paste `dir` in Windows Explorer or other programs, I get an error, the file name is not valid.

I tried the solutions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5186839/6091318) but none worked.
The closest I got is:

```
dir.replace('\\', '/')
'C:/my/folder'
```

Now it works for some windows programs but not others, so I simply want to replace `'\\'` by `'\'`

Comment: Where is the content coming from? Does it output the '\\' form via print() too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're in a python shell and just evaluated the dir, it's sufficient to `print(dir)`.

Otherwise you'd want to do `print(dir.replace('\\\\', '\\'))`, which seems to be a very strange output from os.getcwd()

Keep in mind that '\' is an escape character and thus needs to be escaped itself.

Here's an example from Python shell:

```
>>> a = 'c:\\foo\\bar'
>>> a
'c:\\foo\\bar'
>>> print(a)
c:\foo\bar
```

Comment: (I'm running Linux, so I couldn't quickly test it with os.getcwd())